# python script website blocker is not working even though the script compiles correctly

Tags: python, hosts

The code compiles fine and executes as its supposed to. But when I go to one of the websites in the list of website I created for websites that are supposed to be blocked, I am still able to go to that website. I can still go to www.facebook.com,even though its one of the five websites that my python script is supposed to block

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt

host_temp="hosts.txt"
host_path=r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect="127.0.0.1"


website_list= ["https://www.facebook.com/","www.facebook.com","facebook.com","dub119.mail.live. 
   com","www.dub119.mail.live.com"]

while True:
if  dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,0)<dt.now()< dt(dt.now().year,dt.now().month,dt.now().day,23):
    print("Working hours...")
    with open(host_path,'r+') as file:
        content=file.read()
        # print(content)
        for website in website_list:
            if website in content:
                pass
            else:
                file.write(redirect+"   "+website+"\n")

else:
    with open(host_path,'r+') as file:
        content=file.readlines()
        file.seek(0)
        for line in content:
            if not any(website in line for website in website_list):
                file.write(line)
        file.truncate()

    print("Fun hours..")

time.sleep(4)
```

And I run this code as an Administrator so I know thats not the problem:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lyWU.png)

"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjw17.png)

Comment: What is the contents of your hosts.txt file after running the script?

Comment: I have a screen shot of the hosts files I just added to my original question

Comment: You don't put URLs into that file, just hostnames. In other words: no `https://...`.

Answer (score 0):

`file.write(redirect+"   "+website+"\r\n")`

You need to use Windows line endings. Additionally note that the hosts file should include DNS entries, so `facebook.com` and `www.facebook.com` make sense, but URLs like `https://..` don't.